# apk is fine, but when building aab for google play submission google play services dont start when i download it

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services, il2cpp

So I have a game on app store, I added Google play services

Now when I do an apk build and test it works great really happy with it.

But when I then tick the box for aab ( this is what Google store want uploaded ) it builds it,  I upload it, it rolls out but the Google play stuff fails to work, leaderboard and sign in.

When I extract the apk on my Mac from the aab and install that it works great again.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to check logs of running app? On a device

I have tried

7 different versions of unity (currently on 2019.2.9f1)
Changing the min version of Android API to 21
I exported it as a Gradle project and tried building it like that, again test great on device but play services fail when downloading it from the google play store.

It's using the IL2CPP scripting backend.

Any ideas at this stage are welcome

Answer (score 1):

so after you upload it, google resigns it and gives you a new cert to I had to take this and put it in my google play services API.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it walked readers through the steps to do this, so other devs with the same problem can learn from your experience.